# Android: Shared Preference value doesn't change even after committing

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

**In an Activity_A, i have:**

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

SharedPreference settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn", true);
editor.commit();
```

**in Activity_B i have:**

```
//changing the previously added **city** value
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Activity_A.PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("city", myCity);
editor.commit();
```

**in Activity_C i have:**

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Activity_A.PREFS_NAME, 0);
String city = settings.getString("city", "default");
//here i am getting the previous value of **city**, not the updated 1 from Activity_B
```

But once i restart the application then it gives the correct value.

What am i doing wrong?

Thank You

Comment: In Activity_A you have not committed so please do that if its not done. Other than that every thing seems look fine.

Comment: You want to change in `Activity C` right?

Comment: Only in Activity B you are setting city. So you will get that value in Activity C.

Comment: @Scorpion sorry i missed that line here. It was actually there in my code, updated. thank you

Comment: @SpK No, in Activity_B when i click a button i want to change the value and when i come back to Activity_C i want it to be reflected

Comment: @abbas.aniefa yeah. In Activity_B i am setting say "city1" and run the application few times, after that when i go to Activity_B and change "city1" to "city2" and come back to Activity_C it still shows "City1" until i restart the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Activity C` where you want to show the value, when do you get the value from the `SharedPreferences`?

You should get the `SharedPreferences` values in the `onResume` method i think because if you do this in the `onCreate` method no changes will be there if you co back to `Activity C`.

This is because the `onCreate` method will only be called once the `Activity` is first created. When you navigate back (away) from `Activity C` it goes on the `backstack` and is later restored using the `onRestart` or `onResume`. This means that the `onCreate` method is not called again.

So i suggest that you do the getting from the `SharedPreferences` in the `onResume` method.

Activity lifecylce: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

I'm right?

Rolf